# R count number of rows with duplicate values

Tags: r

Let's say we have this data frame:

```
column_a <- c("a","a","b","c","c","c")
column_b <- c("xx","zz","nn","mm","vv","yy")

df <- data.frame (column_a, column_b)
```

I'm looking to count the number of rows with the same unique values in column_a so that I get something like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(unique = c("a","b","c"), n = c("2","1","3"))
```

So far I tried this but it's not exactly what I'm looking for:

```
df %>% group_by(column_a) %>% mutate(replicate=seq(n()))
```

Comment: `df %>% count(column_a)`?

Comment: That was easier than I thought. Thanks

Comment: One reason your attempt didn't work is that you want to *summarize* the data, returning one row for each group. For that, you could use `df %>% group_by(column_a) %>% summarize(n=n())`, but the briefer version of that is `df %>% count(column_a)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(column_a, column_b) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  group_by(column_a) %>% 
  summarize(n = n())
```

This gives the result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  column_a     n
  <fct>    <int>
1 a            2
2 b            1
3 c            3
```

You can convert it to a data.frame if required.

Comment: What is the point of `select(column_a, column_b) %>%  unique()`?  The `select()` seems pointless and the `unique()` will remove duplicate rows and potentially produce an undercount.

Comment: 1) In case there are other columns.
2)The user wants unique count in the question, just taking into account of that

Comment: (1) `df %>% group_by(column_a) %>% summarize(n=n())` won't care if there are other columns, (2)  OP says they want counts of "unique values in column_a", not... I'm having trouble describing exactly what your code does, something like *"counts of unique `column_a` values in rows that are deduplicated to unique combinations of column_a and column_b"*. (Though I see that if you want (2), then (1) makes sense)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `tally()` or maybe `count`

```
df %>% group_by(column_a) %>% tally()
```